# Python: Extract two dates from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string `s` which contains two dates in it and I am trying to extract these two dates in order to subtract them from each other to count the number of days in between. In the end I am aiming to get a string like this: `s = "o4_24d_20170708_20170801"`

At the company I work we can't install additional packages so I am looking for a solution using native python. Below is what I have so far by using the datetime package which only extracts one date: How can I get both dates out of the string?

```
import re, datetime
s = "o4_20170708_20170801"
match = re.search('\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}', s)
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y%m%d').date()
print date
```

Comment: How exactly do you arrive at `"o4_24d_20170708_20170801"`? In your input (`"o4_20170708_20170801"`) `24` does not exist anywhere.

Comment: regex seems overly complicated for this. Why don't you use ``s.split('_')``?

Comment: Could you post a list of possible inputs? If all of them are the same length, you can just access by index, or split by `_`

Comment: @Ajax1234 sorry maybe it was not clear; I am planning to subtract these two dates and then indicate it in the string.

Comment: @Susenio: unfortunately the input is not always the same length, the strings are taken from filenames with various extensions such as e.g. "o5_20170808_20160801_test.tv14.tif" etc.

Comment: if you always have the same structure, it shouldn't be easier use [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and after that just take the 0-3 digit for the year, 4-5 the month and 6-7 for the day? It less elegant, but it would work xD

EDIT: same structure like `oX_date1_date2_blabla`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

s = "o4_20170708_20170801"
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{8})_(\d{8})')
dates = pattern.search(s)
# dates[0] is full match, dates[1] and dates[2] are captured groups
start = datetime.strptime(dates[1], '%Y%m%d')
end = datetime.strptime(dates[2], '%Y%m%d')
difference = end - start

print(difference.days)
```

will print

```
24
```

then, you could do something like:

```
days = 'd{}_'.format(difference.days)
match_index = dates.start()
new_name = s[:match_index] + days + s[match_index:]
print(new_name)
```

to get

```
o4_d24_20170708_20170801
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, datetime
s = "o4_20170708_20170801"
match = re.findall('\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}', s)
for a_date in match:
  date = datetime.datetime.strptime(a_date, '%Y%m%d').date()
  print date
```

This will print:

```
2017-07-08
2017-08-01
```

Your regex was working correctly at [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=103322)

Comment: The regex can just be simplified to `\d{8}` as well

Comment: sure, I think the issue was with `re.search` not doing what he wanted rather than the reg itself

Comment: @NathanBlaine Thank you, this looks very promising. However I would like to subtract the dates from each other in order to calculate the days inbetween. When I type 'date' into the console I get 'datetime.date(2017,7,8)'. Is it possible to write it into two different variables in order to calculate the days inbetween the two dates?

Comment: @kurdtc it sure is possible! You seem like a capable dude though I bet you can figure it out ;)